# JAX-WS(TomEE) Webservice constructor runs just once

Tags: java, constructor, ejb, jax-ws, apache-tomee

I have JAX-WS webservice, I want to run a method for each request.

I assume that my constructor runs for each request but it runs just once.

I think it happen because tomee use thread pool.
My source code is:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(
    portName = "APIPort",
    serviceName = "APIService",
    targetNamespace = "http://telc.ir/wsdl",
    endpointInterface = "wsAPI.APIWS")
public class API implements APIWS {

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    public API() {
        System.out.println("Webservice Called");
    }
}
```

is there any method that run on each request?

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wager that `@Stateless` might be the culprit here...

Comment: If i remove @Stateless my webservice will not run properly

Comment: If you depend on a new instance being generated for every request, then it's not stateless, is it? It's `@Stateful`.

Comment: when I use Stateless i can use this url for accessing my wsdl: http://localhost:8080/TGUI-API/webservices/API?wsdl when i change it to Stateful the above url doesn't work :(

Comment: is there any method can be run on each request in stateless?

Comment: Sure, use a normal method instead of a contructor. Don't forget the annotations.

Comment: whats the annotation?

Comment: i am sorry i am newbie to jax-ws, i don't know the annotation for this and which library should be import to use that annotation

Comment: I used PostConstruct annotation but it just run once like constructor :(

Answer (score 0):

using constructor for EJB is normally not a feature (and I think it can even not be called on some versions). It is replaced by @PostConstruct to be able to use injection after init. That said it doesn't solve your issue.

You can just declare a facade for your service which will delegate to the EJB which would be a CDI bean @RequestScoped. Same note, use either constructor injections or @PostConstruct to init it but it is done by request ;)